# How to put name of current object in clipboard

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

In Microsoft Access, is there a way in can put the name of the active object in the clipboard, so that I can paste it into code?

Comment: What sort of "active" object? Form? Control? And what is your scenario where you need this?

Comment: @Andre Mainly forms and tables; for example, I may be looking at a table to check something; I then want to put the name of the table into code, therefore I go to the navigation panel, press F2 to select the table name and it says "you cannot rename this object while it is open".

Answer (score 1):

1. Mark (select) the table in question in the Navigation pane
2. Press Ctrl+C
3. Press Ctrl+V
4. Popup opens: Insert table as "Copy of tablename"
5. Press Ctrl+C
6. Close popup
7. Go to code window
8. Press Ctrl+V
9. Delete leading "Copy of " from inserted text